# mechanical disadvantage of pulleys

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have a servo that is fixed and that can move a heavy load approximately one inch.  I need the fixed servo to move a light load approximately 4 inches.  How can I do this with a set of pulleys?  Is it even possible.  I don't have access to any sort of gears or timing belts either, just pulleys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's simply a pulley in reverse - pull on the pulley block and the free end of the rope moves.
It is (or at least was) used in some hydraulic lifts/elevators.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulley] ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulley )

Pulling on the rope (red arrow) with a small force  for a large distance, moves the load (blue arrow) with 4x the force but only 1/4x the distance.
By symmetry you could pull the blue arrow with a force and move the red arrow 4x as far with a smaller force

Comment: Could you draw a picture or elaborate more?  I can't seem to visualize how this would work if the servo is fixed.

Comment: What software are you using?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @captainandcoke - copied image from wiki - see link